# Отправка информации из contentscript.js в background.js

Tags: chrome-extension, sendmessage

*Задача:* получить содержимое html-файла и вставить его на страницу.

*Моя логика:* как только нужная страница загрузилась, `content.js` отправляет сообщение в `background.js`, который в свою очередь берет файл `$.get("_add.html",function(data){}` и отправляет информацию обратно в `content.js`

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple - заглянул сюда. Вроде бы, первый вариант наиболее подходящий. Работает. Далее стал подключать свой файл, из которого необходимо получить информацию. Саму отправку совершить не получается

***Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать ???***

Все файлы - https://github.com/bart96-b/sendMessage

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "description": "description",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],

    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "https://www.google.ru/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ]
    }]
}
```

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "hello"){
            $.get("add.html",function(data){
                sendResponse(data);     // Не передается (1)
                sendResponse("123");    // Не передается (2)
            })

            //  sendResponse(data);     // Не передается (3)
            //  sendResponse("456");    // Передается (4)
        }
    }
);
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось значительно проще.

**content.js**

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('html/bloks/SuperMenu.html'), function(data){
    condole.log(data);
});
```